# Android logging touches

Tags: android, touch, listener, overlay, monitor

I try to build up a UI testing environment and I would like to log all touch events and their coordinates.

At the moment I have to scenarios:
1. I use a transparent overlay which successfully logs everything but I'm not able to click the buttons etc. on the view below. 
2. I can click the buttons below but the overlay doesn't log the coordinates...

Unfortunately both doesn't work. Therefore I would like to know if there is any way that both works?

Thanks!

Code snippet of the overlay window:

```
oView = new LinearLayout(this);  
oView.setBackgroundColor(0x88ff0000); // The translucent red color
WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);       
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
wm.addView(oView, params);
```

Moreover I create a ontouchlistener for the oView...

Answer (score 0):

The `FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH` "trick" was a security exploit and was patched out in Android 4.2+

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/79e0206ef3203a1842949242e58fa8f3c25eb129/services/input/InputDispatcher.cpp#L1417)'s the relevant section in the Andoird source.

As you can see from the comment, if the touch is not inside your overlay a special flag is set that nulls the coordinates.
This is obviously done to stop keylogging and other touch-hijacking exploits.

The only alternative I know of is to have a rooted device and to read directly from the underlying linux kernel event interface by calling something like:

```
getevent -lt /dev/input/eventX
```

from a root shell. The `l` flag makes the output more human-readable and the `t` flag will attach timestamps to the output, in case you need them.
Note that X is the ID of the touchscreen device. You can get info on the available devices using the command `getevent -lp`, the touchscreen is the one that has the `ABS_MT_POSITION_X` and `ABS_MT_POSITION_Y` events.

Note however that the data you'll get is very low-level and you'll have to parse it yourself into something useful. You can check out the [linux kernel documentation on multi-touch devices](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/multi-touch-protocol.txt) for info on what exactly the various event codes mean.